# How to make edit node display all the nodes menu links

Tags: 8, nodes, navigation

I have a site with a lot of content and some of it is linked in multiple menus (for example: one in the footer menu and another in a submenu of a page).

By default, Drupal displays the first menu link for the node when editing it, is there a way to have it display all menu links for it, and also allow adding multiple links?

I haven't found any modules that solve this issue, and my googling as so far turned up nothing helpful, so any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't know any solution that handles this on the node edit page, you have to use the menu UI for this.

Comment: @Hudri True, that is how it's handled today, but the problem is that the person who is editing the node does not have a full list of menu items linking to the node, meaning that if they decide to delete the node, there might end up being menu links not working